# How to chunk shell script input by time, not by size?

Tags: bash, buffer, chunking

In a bash script I am using a many-producer single-consumer pattern. Producers are background processes writing lines into a fifo (via GNU Parallel). The consumer reads all lines from the fifo, then sorts, filters, and prints the formatted result to stdout.

However, it could take a long time until the full result is available. Producers are usually fast on the first few results but then would slow down. Here I am more interested to see chunks of data every few seconds, each sorted and filtered individually.

```sh
mkfifo fifo
parallel ... >"$fifo" &
while chunk=$(read with timeout 5s and at most 10s <"$fifo"); do
  process "$chunk"
done
```

The loop would run until all producers are done and all input is read. Each chunk is read until there has been no new data for 5s, or until 10s have passed since the chunk was started. A chunk may also be empty if there was no new data for 10s.

I tried to make it work like this:

```sh
output=$(mktemp)
while true; do
  wasTimeout=0 interruptAt=$(( $(date '+%s') + 10 ))
  while true; do
    IFS= read -r -t5 <>"${fifo}"
    rc="$?"
    if [[ "${rc}" -gt 0 ]]; then
      [[ "${rc}" -gt 128 ]] && wasTimeout=1
      break
    fi
    echo "$REPLY" >>"${output}"
    if [[ $(date '+%s') -ge "${interruptAt}" ]]; then
      wasTimeout=1
      break
    fi
  done
  echo '---' >>"${output}"
  [[ "${wasTimeout}" -eq 0 ]] && break
done
```

Tried some variations of this. In the form above it reads the first chunk but then loops forever. If I use `<"${fifo}"` (no read/write as above) it blocks after the first chunk. Maybe all of this could be simplified with `buffer` and/or `stdbuf`? But both of them define blocks by size, not by time.

Comment: There comes a point at which it is easier to write the code in C than in shell.  My gut feel says this chunking functionality has reached that point.  There is one gotcha that you'd have to deal with — you need a process to hold the FIFO open for reading (without actually reading any data) so that data is not lost as a C program opens the FIFO, reads a chunk, closes the FIFO (possibly implicitly by just exiting) and returns.  Others may beg to differ.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: so far Bash could handle all I threw at it and this problem looked innocuous until I tried to solve it. I wonder if a subshell with just the `read -t3` in it, reading from one fifo, buffering the reads, then writing into another would work. How would it distinguish a) fifo has no writers anymore, no more data to come from b) fifo is empty but more data may arrive later... I don't want to start another `read` if there are no more writers for the fifo.

Comment: Yes, it is a tricky problem, and not one that is readily programmed in a shell script.  I use C automatically; equivalent programs could be written using C++ and Perl for sure, probably Python and Java too (and quite likely other languages too).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a trivial problem to resolve.  As I hinted, a C program (or a program in some programming language other than the shell) is probably the best solution.  Some of the complicating factors are:

- Reading with timeouts.
- If data arrives soon enough, the timeout changes.
- Different systems have different sets of interval timing functions:

  - [`alarm()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/alarm.html) is likely available everywhere, but has only 1-second resolution which is liable to accumulated rounding errors.  (Compile this version with `make UFLAGS=-DUSE_ALARM`; on macOS, use `make UFLAGS=-DUSE_ALARM LDLIB2=`.)
  - [`setitimer()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/setitimer.html)
    uses microsecond timing and the `struct timeval` type. (Compile this version with `make UFLAGS=-DUSE_SETITIMER`; on macOS, compile with `make UFLAGS=-DUSE_SETITIMER LDLIB2=`.)
  - [`timer_create()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/timer_create.html) and
    [`timer_settime()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/timer_settime.html) etc use the modern nanosecond type `struct timespec`.  This is available on Linux; it is not available on macOS 10.14.5 Mojave or earlier.  (Compile this version with `make`; it won't work on macOS.)

The program usage message is:

```
$ chunker79 -h
Usage: chunker79 [-hvV][-c chunk][-d delay][-f file]
  -c chunk  Maximum time to wait for data in a chunk (default 10)
  -d delay  Maximum delay after line read (default: 5)
  -f file   Read from file instead of standard input
  -h        Print this help message and exit
  -v        Verbose mode: print timing information to stderr
  -V        Print version information and exit

$
```

This code is available in my [SOQ](https://github.com/jleffler/soq) (Stack Overflow Questions) repository on GitHub as file `chunker79.c` in the [src/so-5631-4784](https://github.com/jleffler/soq/tree/master/src/so-5631-4784) sub-directory.   You will need some of the support code from the src/libsoq directory too.

```c
/*
@(#)File:           chunker79.c
@(#)Purpose:        Chunk Reader for SO 5631-4784
@(#)Author:         J Leffler
@(#)Copyright:      (C) JLSS 2019
*/

/*TABSTOP=4*/

/*
** Problem specification from the Stack Overflow question
**
** In a bash script I am using a many-producer single-consumer pattern.
** Producers are background processes writing lines into a fifo (via GNU
** Parallel).  The consumer reads all lines from the fifo, then sorts,
** filters, and prints the formatted result to stdout.
**
** However, it could take a long time until the full result is
** available.  Producers are usually fast on the first few results but
** then would slow down.  Here I am more interested to see chunks of
** data every few seconds, each sorted and filtered individually.
**
**    mkfifo fifo
**    parallel ... >"$fifo" &
**    while chunk=$(read with timeout 5s and at most 10s <"$fifo"); do
**      process "$chunk"
**    done
**
** The loop would run until all producers are done and all input is
** read.  Each chunk is read until there has been no new data for 5s, or
** until 10s have passed since the chunk was started.  A chunk may also
** be empty if there was no new data for 10s.
*/

/*
** Analysis
**
** 1.  If no data arrives at all for 10 seconds, then the program should
**     terminate producing no output.  This timeout is controlled by the
**     value of time_chunk in the code.
** 2.  If data arrives more or less consistently, then the collection
**     should continue for 10s and then finish.  This timeout is also
**     controlled by the value of time_chunk in the code.
** 3.  If a line of data arrives before 5 seconds have elapsed, and no
**     more arrives for 5 seconds, then the collection should finish.
**     (If the first line arrives after 5 seconds and no more arrives
**     for more than 5 seconds, then the 10 second timeout cuts in.)
**     This timeout is controlled by the value of time_delay in the code.
** 4.  This means that we want two separate timers at work:
**     - Chunk timer (started when the program starts).
**     - Delay timer (started each time a line is read).
**
** It doesn't matter which timer goes off, but further timer signals
** should be ignored.  External signals will confuse things; tough!
**
** -- Using alarm(2) is tricky because it provides only one time, not two.
** -- Using getitimer(2), setitimer(2) uses obsolescent POSIX functions,
**    but these are available on macOS.
** -- Using timer_create(2), timer_destroy(2), timer_settime(2),
**    timer_gettime(2) uses current POSIX function but is not available
**    on macOS.
*/

#include "posixver.h"

#include "stderr.h"
#include "timespec_io.h"
#include <assert.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/uio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#ifdef USE_SETITIMER
#include "timeval_math.h"
#include "timeval_io.h"
#include <sys/time.h>
#endif /* USE_SETITIMER */

static const char optstr[] = "hvVc:d:f:";
static const char usestr[] = "[-hvV][-c chunk][-d delay][-f file]";
static const char hlpstr[] =
    "  -c chunk  Maximum time to wait for data in a chunk (default 10)\n"
    "  -d delay  Maximum delay after line read (default: 5)\n"
    "  -f file   Read from file instead of standard input\n"
    "  -h        Print this help message and exit\n"
    "  -v        Verbose mode: print timing information to stderr\n"
    "  -V        Print version information and exit\n"
    ;

static struct timespec time_delay = { .tv_sec =  5, .tv_nsec = 0 };
static struct timespec time_chunk = { .tv_sec = 10, .tv_nsec = 0 };
static struct timespec time_start;

static bool verbose = false;

static void set_chunk_timeout(void);
static void set_delay_timeout(void);
static void cancel_timeout(void);
static void alarm_handler(int signum);

// Using signal() manages to set SA_RESTART on a Mac.
// This is allowed by standard C and POSIX, sadly.
// signal(SIGALRM, alarm_handler);

#if defined(USE_ALARM)

static void set_chunk_timeout(void)
{
    if (verbose)
        err_remark("-->> %s()\n", __func__);
    alarm(time_chunk.tv_sec);
    struct sigaction sa;
    sa.sa_handler = alarm_handler;
    sigemptyset(&sa.sa_mask);
    sa.sa_flags = 0;
    sigaction(SIGALRM, &sa, NULL);
    if (verbose)
        err_remark("<<-- %s()\n", __func__);
}

static void set_delay_timeout(void)
{
    if (verbose)
        err_remark("-->> %s()\n", __func__);
    unsigned time_left = alarm(0);
    if (time_left > time_delay.tv_sec)
        alarm(time_delay.tv_sec);
    else
        alarm(time_left);
    if (verbose)
        err_remark("<<-- %s()\n", __func__);
}

static void cancel_timeout(void)
{
    if (verbose)
        err_remark("-->> %s()\n", __func__);
    alarm(0);
    signal(SIGALRM, SIG_IGN);
    if (verbose)
        err_remark("<<-- %s()\n", __func__);
}

#elif defined(USE_SETITIMER)

static inline struct timeval cvt_timespec_to_timeval(struct timespec ts)
{
    return (struct timeval){ .tv_sec = ts.tv_sec, .tv_usec = ts.tv_nsec / 1000 };
}

static void set_chunk_timeout(void)
{
    if (verbose)
        err_remark("-->> %s()\n", __func__);
    struct itimerval tv_new = { { 0, 0 }, { 0, 0 } };
    tv_new.it_value = cvt_timespec_to_timeval(time_chunk);
    struct itimerval tv_old;
    if (setitimer(ITIMER_REAL, &tv_new, &tv_old) != 0)
        err_syserr("failed to set interval timer: ");
    struct sigaction sa;
    sa.sa_handler = alarm_handler;
    sigemptyset(&sa.sa_mask);
    sa.sa_flags = 0;
    sigaction(SIGALRM, &sa, NULL);
    if (verbose)
        err_remark("<<-- %s()\n", __func__);
}

static void set_delay_timeout(void)
{
    if (verbose)
        err_remark("-->> %s()\n", __func__);
    struct itimerval tv_until;
    if (getitimer(ITIMER_REAL, &tv_until) != 0)
        err_syserr("failed to set interval timer: ");
    struct timeval tv_delay = cvt_timespec_to_timeval(time_delay);

    if (verbose)
    {
        char buff1[32];
        fmt_timeval(&tv_delay, 6, buff1, sizeof(buff1));
        char buff2[32];
        fmt_timeval(&tv_until.it_value, 6, buff2, sizeof(buff2));
        err_remark("---- %s(): delay %s, left %s\n", __func__, buff1, buff2);
    }

    if (cmp_timeval(tv_until.it_value, tv_delay) <= 0)
    {
        if (verbose)
            err_remark("---- %s(): no need for delay timer\n", __func__);
    }
    else
    {
        struct itimerval tv_new = { { 0, 0 }, { 0, 0 } };
        tv_new.it_value = cvt_timespec_to_timeval(time_delay);
        struct itimerval tv_old;
        if (setitimer(ITIMER_REAL, &tv_new, &tv_old) != 0)
            err_syserr("failed to set interval timer: ");
        if (verbose)
            err_remark("---- %s(): set delay timer\n", __func__);
    }
    if (verbose)
        err_remark("<<-- %s()\n", __func__);
}

static void cancel_timeout(void)
{
    if (verbose)
        err_remark("-->> %s()\n", __func__);
    struct itimerval tv_new =
    {
        .it_value    = { .tv_sec = 0, .tv_usec = 0 },
        .it_interval = { .tv_sec = 0, .tv_usec = 0 },
    };
    struct itimerval tv_old;
    if (setitimer(ITIMER_REAL, &tv_new, &tv_old) != 0)
        err_syserr("failed to set interval timer: ");
    if (verbose)
        err_remark("<<-- %s()\n", __func__);
}

#else /* USE_TIMER_GETTIME */

#include "timespec_math.h"

static timer_t t0 = { 0 };

static void set_chunk_timeout(void)
{
    if (verbose)
        err_remark("-->> %s()\n", __func__);

    struct sigevent ev =
    {
        .sigev_notify = SIGEV_SIGNAL,
        .sigev_signo = SIGALRM,
        .sigev_value.sival_int = 0,
        .sigev_notify_function = 0,
        .sigev_notify_attributes = 0,
    };
    if (timer_create(CLOCK_REALTIME, &ev, &t0) < 0)
        err_syserr("failed to create a timer: ");

    struct itimerspec it =
    {
        .it_interval = { .tv_sec = 0, .tv_nsec = 0 },
        .it_value = time_chunk,
    };
    struct itimerspec ot;
    if (timer_settime(t0, 0, &it, &ot) != 0)
        err_syserr("failed to activate timer: ");

    struct sigaction sa;
    sa.sa_handler = alarm_handler;
    sigemptyset(&sa.sa_mask);
    sa.sa_flags = 0;
    sigaction(SIGALRM, &sa, NULL);
    if (verbose)
        err_remark("<<-- %s()\n", __func__);
}

static void set_delay_timeout(void)
{
    if (verbose)
        err_remark("-->> %s()\n", __func__);
    struct itimerspec time_until;
    if (timer_gettime(t0, &time_until) != 0)
        err_syserr("failed to set per-process timer: ");

    char buff1[32];
    fmt_timespec(&time_delay, 6, buff1, sizeof(buff1));
    char buff2[32];
    fmt_timespec(&time_until.it_value, 6, buff2, sizeof(buff2));
    err_remark("---- %s(): delay %s, left %s\n", __func__, buff1, buff2);

    if (cmp_timespec(time_until.it_value, time_delay) <= 0)
    {
        if (verbose)
            err_remark("---- %s(): no need for delay timer\n", __func__);
    }
    else
    {
        struct itimerspec time_new =
        {
            .it_interval = { .tv_sec = 0, .tv_nsec = 0 },
            .it_value = time_delay,
        };
        struct itimerspec time_old;
        if (timer_settime(t0, 0, &time_new, &time_old) != 0)
            err_syserr("failed to set per-process timer: ");
        if (verbose)
            err_remark("---- %s(): set delay timer\n", __func__);
    }
    if (verbose)
        err_remark("<<-- %s()\n", __func__);
}

static void cancel_timeout(void)
{
    if (timer_delete(t0) != 0)
        err_syserr("failed to delete timer: ");
}

#endif /* Timing mode */

/* Writing to stderr via err_remark() is not officially supported */
static void alarm_handler(int signum)
{
    assert(signum == SIGALRM);
    if (verbose)
        err_remark("---- %s(): signal %d\n", __func__, signum);
}

static void read_chunks(FILE *fp)
{
    size_t num_data = 0;
    size_t max_data = 0;
    struct iovec *data = 0;
    size_t buflen = 0;
    char *buffer = 0;
    ssize_t length;
    size_t chunk_len = 0;

    clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &time_start);

    set_chunk_timeout();
    while ((length = getline(&buffer, &buflen, fp)) != -1)
    {
        if (num_data >= max_data)
        {
            size_t new_size = (num_data * 2) + 2;
            void *newspace = realloc(data, new_size * sizeof(data[0]));
            if (newspace == 0)
                err_syserr("failed to allocate %zu bytes data: ", new_size * sizeof(data[0]));
            data = newspace;
            max_data = new_size;
        }
        data[num_data].iov_base = buffer;
        data[num_data].iov_len = length;
        num_data++;
        if (verbose)
            err_remark("Received line %zu\n", num_data);
        chunk_len += length;
        buffer = 0;
        buflen = 0;
        set_delay_timeout();
    }
    cancel_timeout();

    if (chunk_len > 0)
    {
        if ((length = writev(STDOUT_FILENO, data, num_data)) < 0)
            err_syserr("failed to write %zu bytes to standard output: ", chunk_len);
        else if ((size_t)length != chunk_len)
            err_error("failed to write %zu bytes to standard output "
                      "(short write of %zu bytes)\n", chunk_len, (size_t)length);
    }

    if (verbose)
        err_remark("---- %s(): data written (%zu bytes)\n", __func__, length);

    for (size_t i = 0; i < num_data; i++)
        free(data[i].iov_base);
    free(data);
    free(buffer);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    const char *name = "(standard input)";
    FILE *fp = stdin;
    err_setarg0(argv[0]);
    err_setlogopts(ERR_MICRO);

    int opt;
    while ((opt = getopt(argc, argv, optstr)) != -1)
    {
        switch (opt)
        {
        case 'c':
            if (scn_timespec(optarg, &time_chunk) != 0)
                err_error("Failed to convert '%s' into a time value\n", optarg);
            break;
        case 'd':
            if (scn_timespec(optarg, &time_delay) != 0)
                err_error("Failed to convert '%s' into a time value\n", optarg);
            break;
        case 'f':
            if ((fp = fopen(optarg, "r")) == 0)
                err_syserr("Failed to open file '%s' for reading: ", optarg);
            name = optarg;
            break;
        case 'h':
            err_help(usestr, hlpstr);
            /*NOTREACHED*/
        case 'v':
            verbose = true;
            break;
        case 'V':
            err_version("CHUNKER79", &"@(#)$Revision$ ($Date$)"[4]);
            /*NOTREACHED*/
        default:
            err_usage(usestr);
            /*NOTREACHED*/
        }
    }

    if (optind != argc)
        err_usage(usestr);

    if (verbose)
    {
        err_remark("chunk: %3lld.%09ld\n", (long long)time_chunk.tv_sec, time_chunk.tv_nsec);
        err_remark("delay: %3lld.%09ld\n", (long long)time_delay.tv_sec, time_delay.tv_nsec);
        err_remark("file:  %s\n", name);
    }

    read_chunks(fp);

    return 0;
}
```

My SOQ repository also has a script `gen-data.sh` which makes use of some custom programs to generate a data stream such as this (the seed value is written to standard error, not standard output):

```
$ gen-data.sh
# Seed: 1313715286
2019-06-03 23:04:16.653: Zunmieoprri Rdviqymcho 5878 2017-03-29 03:59:15 Udransnadioiaeamprirteo
2019-06-03 23:04:18.525: Rndflseoevhgs Etlaevieripeoetrnwkn 9500 2015-12-18 10:49:15 Ebyrcoebeezatiagpleieoefyc
2019-06-03 23:04:20.526: Nrzsuiakrooab Nbvliinfqidbujoops 1974 2020-05-13 08:05:14 Lgithearril
2019-06-03 23:04:21.777: Eeagop Aieneose 6533 2016-11-06 22:51:58 Aoejlwebbssroncmeovtuuueigraa
2019-06-03 23:04:23.876: Izirdoeektau Atesltiybysaclee 4557 2020-09-13 02:24:46 Igrooiaauiwtna
2019-06-03 23:04:26.145: Yhioit Eamrexuabagsaraiw 9703 2014-09-13 07:44:12 Dyiiienglolqopnrbneerltnmsdn
^C
$
```

When fed into `chunker79` with default options, I get output like:

```
$ gen-data.sh | chunker79
# Seed: 722907235
2019-06-03 23:06:20.570: Aluaezkgiebeewal Oyvahee 1022 2015-08-12 07:45:54 Weuababeeduklleym
2019-06-03 23:06:24.100: Gmujvoyevihvoilc Negeiiuvleem 8196 2015-08-29 21:15:15 Nztkrvsadeoeagjgoyotvertavedi
$
```

If you analyze the time intervals (look at the first two fields in the output lines), that output meets the specification.  A still more detailed analysis is shown by:

```
$ timecmd -mr -- gen-data.sh | timecmd -mr -- chunker79
2019-06-03 23:09:14.246 [PID 57159] gen-data.sh
2019-06-03 23:09:14.246 [PID 57160] chunker79
# Seed: -1077610201
2019-06-03 23:09:14.269: Woreio Rdtpimvoscttbyhxim 7893 2017-03-12 12:46:57 Uywaietirkekes
2019-06-03 23:09:16.939: Uigaba Nzoxdeuisofai 3630 2017-11-16 09:28:59 Jnsncgoesycsevdscugoathusaoq
2019-06-03 23:09:17.845: Sscreua Aloaoonnsuur 5163 2016-08-13 19:47:15 Injhsiifqovbnyeooiimitaaoir
2019-06-03 23:09:19.272 [PID 57160; status 0x0000]  -  5.026s  -  chunker79
2019-06-03 23:09:22.084 [PID 57159; status 0x8D00]  -  7.838s  -  gen-data.sh
$
```

There is a noticeable pause in this setup between when the output from `chunker79` appears and when `gen-data.sh` completes.  That's due to Bash waiting on all processes in the pipeline to complete, and `gen-data.sh` doesn't complete until the next time it writes to the pipe after the message that finishes `chunker79`.  This is an artefact of this test setup; it wouldn't be a factor in the shell script outlined in the question.

Comment: Wow. This is a lot more than I could even hope for. I'll check it out tonight.

Comment: After I tricked myself a few times I could confirm that this works as advertised, so thanks again. I could not use gendata.sh (dribbler?) but for this purpose something simple sufficed: `while sleep 1s; do echo $(( c++ )); done | while chunk=$(./chunker79); do echo -e "${chunk}\n---"; done` (and variations of this). Still need to decide whether to call it again after receiving no data (is there still a writing process for the fifo if the last chunk was empty?). But I will simply append an EOF marker and check for that.

Comment: All three programs used by `gen-data.sh` (`random`, `dribbler`, `tstamp`) are C programs I created (though I'd be unsurprised to find other people with different programs called `random`).  Code available on request — see my profile.  The `random` program has a fairly good core but has not yet got a good interface.

Comment: You could create a simple program (certainly in C, probably even in shell — GNU `timeout` might help) that tries to open the FIFO but fails if it takes more than N seconds (where N might be 1, or perhaps 5) to be successful.  That means there is no process with the FIFO open for writing.  You probably need a process lurking in the background with the FIFO open for reading — you'd kill that lurker when you detect no writers.  And maybe you'd remove the FIFO.

Answer (score 0):

I would consider writing a safe multi-threaded program with queues.

I know Java better, but there might be more modern suitable languages like Go and Kotlin.

Comment: Actually I have considered Java first. Here I am interfacing with a C library and would have needed to port it to Java or getting started with JNI. Both options did not seem too enjoyable. Maybe I'll try Rust some time.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

$timeout = 3;
while(<STDIN>) {
    # Make sure there is some input                                                      
    push @out,$_;
    eval {
        local $SIG{ALRM} = sub { die };
        alarm $timeout;
        while(<STDIN>) {
            alarm $timeout;
            push @out,$_;
        }
        alarm 0;
    };
    system "echo","process",@out;
}
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestion (and for making parallel :). I don't mind using Perl as long as I don't have to understand all of it... I tried the above and it has some problems. Consider this for a test: `c=0; while sleep 1s; do echo $(( c++ )); done | ./x.pl`. It should print whatever it got after max 3s (or 10s if no input received) but does not output anything. Change the sleep to 4s and now the timeout is working but each output repeats the previous output plus new input from stdin.

Answer (score 0):

GNU Parallel 20200122 introduced `--blocktimeout` (`--bt`):

```
find ~ | parallel -j3 --bt 2s --pipe wc
```

This works like normal GNU Parallel except if it takes > 2 seconds to fill a block. In that case the block read so far is simply passed to `wc` (unless it is empty).

It has a slightly odd startup behaviour: You have to wait 3*2s (jobslots*timeout) before the output stabilizes, and you get an output at least every 2s.